# Deletion in singly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have this function `deleteNode()` for deleting a node from a linked list. This func. is called in the main func. like this `deleteNode(&head, 10);`, where `head` is the pointer to the first node of the linked list and `10` the value to be deleted.

Here, the `else if` statement is commented and the function runs fine. But when I uncomment the `else if` statement and run then the program crashes. Why is it happening and what is the solution?

```
void deleteNode(node **h, int value)
{
    node *current, *temp;
    current = *h;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        // if the node to be deleted is the first node of the list
        if(current == *h && current->data == value)    
        {
            *h = current->next;
        }
        /*
        // if the node to be deleted is other than first node
        else if(current->next->data == value)
        {
            temp = current->next;
            current->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
        } */
        current = current->next;
    }                  
}
```

Comment: Because you don't check if `current->next` is NULL or not, you just access it. Running the code in debugger always helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to access `current->next->data` without checking if the `current->next` is null first. You should modify your logic either to check if `current->next != null` before trying to access its data, or to check the `current->data` and remove it by saving the `previous` node also.

Comment: ok, I think the problem occurs when `current` points to the last node

Comment: Sure, because it has no next. You're right. Just improve your logic and it should work

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are trying to delete a single node from linked list with a given value, but since you are continuing the loop it will delete all the nodes with the given value after you fix the bug i.e. checking **current->next != NULL** before checking its data. You could refer to the following code to delete a single node.

```
void deleteNode(node **h, int value)
{
    node *current, *temp;
    current = *h;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        // if the node to be deleted is the first node of the list
        if(current == *h && current->data == value)    
        {
            *h = current->next;
             free(current);
             return;

        }

        // if the node to be deleted is other than first node
        else if(current->next != NULL && current->next->data == value)
        {
            temp = current->next;
            current->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            return;
        } 
        current = current->next;
    }                  
}
```